# Combine EditText, TextView and Preference

Tags: android, listview, layout

is it possible to a view that contained a Block with TextView, Editext and a second Block that contains a PreferenceScreen with (Checkbox, List, Chexbox etc...)

What i want to do, is somethink like this. The first block has a 2 EditText and 2 TextView for Title, and Message. In the second block (at the botttom) i want to configure some stoof.

Please how can i make it. I want the bottom Block to look like a List View. When i make a Hover on each item i want this item to look like a listview item

---

I tried it like this, but it does not work! I defined the inflated class as a public static class in MyActivity class. What am i doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >             
            <view
                class="com.app.MyActivity$PrefsFragment"
                id="@+id/prayerFormPref"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Yes possible. You can use [linearlayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you wish to create a custom View that is just a composite of other View objects, you should extend a layout (Like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and so on).

In your extended layout, you can inflate a sub-layout or View from XML (use LayoutInflater).
Or, you can add all child views programatically using their constructors, and ViewGroup.addView().

The SDK guide explains this thoroughly:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Comment: can you show me how i can create a View like the image i shown in my first post please?

Comment: I gave the answer - you extend a layout. LinearLayout would be good for creating the header + 2 items and replicate it. Did you try that?

Comment: I have the code posted above, please can you check it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Define it as a separate class, not an inner class. And show the custom layout code itself.